# Why K-means is so used for document clustering?

Tags: cluster-analysis, document, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, clustering-key

Can someone explain to me why the K-means algorithm is so used (especially in documents clustering) despite its defects, instead of K-medoids for example, or CAH, SOM etc.?

Comment: Says who? Just because k-means is a popular textbook intro does not mean it is actually used much (in particular not *successfully*). And why do you think k-medoids would be a better choice? Document collections tend to be huge.

Comment: Thanks Anony-Mousse. This is a quite new subject for me. I have seen many documents clustering applications in scientific articles with Kmeans, hence my bias.
Regarding the K-medoid, I read that it was created to be more robust to noise and outliers than Kmeans. My dataset is not really huge, so K-medoid could be better.

Comment: Or it could be worse. Or both could be really bad, just that the average author doesn't know anything better. Or doesn't care, as long as there is *some* output...

Comment: You're right ! You look expert in data mining and clustering, 
Which algorithms do you use the most?

Comment: Whatever fits the problem best. I don't want to name "favorites" because I always tell people to make informed choices, not guesses based on general recommendations.